# Android Request Permission Callback

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to implement Android permissions from https://developers.google.com/android/guides/permissions

A couple of ques:
1) The callback onRequestPermissionResult - where are the parameters String[] permissions and int[]grantResults from? 
2) I keep getting null values for grantResults and String[] permissions
3) I have set the value of the const REQUEST_LOCATION to 0 - does it matter what the value of this const is?

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  // Check Permissions Now
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
        REQUEST_LOCATION);
} else {
  // permission has been granted, continue as usual
  Location myLocation =
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
}
```

One unrelated ques...when getting a google map API key is it required to set the SHA-1 value or is that optional and just limits the key to android.

Thanks.

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults)
```

Comment: "where are the parameters String[] permissions and int[]grantResults from?" -- the `String[]` should contain the strings that you passed into `requestPermissions()`. The `int[]` contains the corresponding statuses of those permissions (e.g., granted). Personally, I never use these. "does it matter what the value of this const is?" -- it needs to be distinct across all `requestPermisions()` and `startActivityForResult()` calls coming from this activity or its fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class RequestUserPermission {

```
private Activity activity;


// Storage Permissions
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
};

public RequestUserPermission(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public  boolean verifyStoragePermissions() {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permissionWrite = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permissionRead = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if ((permissionWrite != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
            (permissionRead != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS,
                REQUEST_PERMISSION
        );
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

public void providePermission(){
    verifyStoragePermissions();
}

public void forceFullOpenPermission(){
    if(!verifyStoragePermissions()){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", activity.getPackageName(), null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
    }
}
```

**In your Activity**

```
RequestUserPermission requestUserPermission = new 
RequestUserPermission(DashBoard.this);
    requestUserPermission.verifyStoragePermissions();
```

**If you want to forceful open permission**

```
requestUserPermission.forceFullOpenPermission();
```

Comment: you can add any permission in PERMISSION[ ] and can verify using method verifyStoragePermissions()

Answer (score 2):

Get your run time permission like this

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission already Granted
                    //Do your work here
//Perform operations here only which requires permission
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }
```

and if permission is not already granted override onRequestPermission Results like this

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            //Permission Granted
                            //Do your work here
//Perform operations here only which requires permission
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) request code is the one you named it `REQUEST_LOCATION` with value of 0. `permissions` is the requests you have sent. for example you can request for Location permission and Read SMS permission at once so you will get them in permissions string array. and `grantResults` is the status of each requests for example if user accepts Location request it will be 1 and if he rejected Read SMS it will be 0

2)I think this means you have rejected the request

3)With that if you have requested multiple times from different places you can determine which result is for which request

and answer of your unrelated question: no it's optional and if you don't  want other applications uses your key you have to set that

Answer (score 0):

1) The callback onRequestPermissionResult - where are the parameters String[] permissions and int[]grantResults from?

**permissions is the list of permissions you requested and grantResults are the results of those requests. So since you only requested one permission (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), you will get back ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in permissions, and either PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED or PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED in grantResults**

2) I keep getting null values for grantResults and String[] permissions

**This means that the user did not click Accept or Decline in the permission dialog. Rather, they cancelled the dialog by clicking outside of it, or leaving the application.**

3) I have set the value of the const REQUEST_LOCATION to 0 - does it matter what the value of this const is?

**No, this can be anything**