# constant for fine_location permission android

Tags: android

I searched for how to initialise requestPermissions and found the code below:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity)mContext, 
android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)mContext, new String[]{
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
}, Integer constant required);
```

It requires a third parameter which is Inter constant for FINE LOCATION.
I could not find that. Please help me with this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43760891/4336740

Comment: try above link may help you...

Comment: That integer is something your provide, it can be anything you want. It is used for the callback in `onRequestPermissionsResult` to identify what permission you asked for so you can check

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference .  This is the exception I am getting if I do not use the above code mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A third parameter is requestCode of permission,
you can create it constant 
like below

```
private int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 23; //you can pass any code here
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)mContext, new String[]{
    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
```

this parameter is used to compare with requestCode of first parameter of onRequestPermissionsResult method while override it.

```
   @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        //Checking the request code of our request
        if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

            //If permission is granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == 0) {

                //Displaying a toast
                Toast.makeText(context, "Permission granted now.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
               Toast.makeText(context, "Permission denied.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I spend my time on your question, you can at least up vote it. Thank You

Comment: Does onRequestPermissionsResult() work in a non activity class?

Comment: do you mean in fragment class ?

Comment: It is not a fragment class. I have created a separate class which extends Service and implements LocationListener.

Comment: No, in a Service you can't add a onRequestPermissionsResult() because this method is added in sdk level 23 (marshmallow), which come with context or activity, i suggest, if you need this method, you can call this method above line of you called service, as i seems you've called the service in some activity or fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Third param is RequestCode.

Application specific request code to match with a result reported to onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]).

Should be >= 0.

For more info, see this. [ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int))

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Isn't it predefined?

Comment: Actually it should not be mandatory but they are asking so pass any value>0 but except any request code which you are using in the same activity.